# ValueError when query single param

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have the code to retrieve the data from the SQLite db. Querying the whole object works fine, but when querying one param it returns ValueError.

Here is my db code

```
import contextlib
from contextlib import contextmanager, AbstractContextManager
from typing import Callable

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from app.definitions import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
from app.infrastructure.logging.logger import logger
from app.models.base import Base

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})
session_factory = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))


@measure_time
def create() -> None:
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


@contextmanager
def session() -> Callable[..., AbstractContextManager[Session]]:
    session: Session = session_factory()
    try:
        yield session
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f'Exception generating database session: {e}')
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Here is test_repository

```
from app.infrastructure.db import db
from app.infrastructure.logging.logger import logger


class TestRepository:

    def get_tests(self):
        with db.session() as session:
            logger.debug(f'Session: {session}')
            tests = session.query(Test.name).all()
            logger.debug(tests)
            return tests
```

I'm using the repository in my endpoint

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

from repositories.test_repository import TestRepository

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/tests",
    tags=["Tests"],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
)

test_repository = TestRepository()


@router.get("/")
async def get_tests():
    return test_repository.get_tests()
```

When logging the query result I could see that the result is fine but when return it I get

```
ValueError: [ValueError('dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 32; 2 is required'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How are you using your TestRepository? There doesn't seem to be any code that actually uses the repository? Which line triggers the error? (i.e. does it occur after returning from the controller?)

Comment: @MatsLindh I added an endpoint from which I call the repository method. (updated the question) The error seems to occur in `return tests` in the repository raising ValueError in `\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 160, in jsonable_encoder`.
When I log the query, it seems fine - a list of `<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>` objects and it works fine when I query the whole Test object. 
I also tried to return an empty list and with that it works fine too.

Comment: FastAPI has no idea how to serialize Row objects. You'll either have to convert them to a dictionary yourself, or use a response model with `orm_mode=True` set in its inner `Config` class: https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances and https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/

Comment: try this session.query(Test).filter(Test.name).one_or_none()